# Why would a theme writer put their CSS in one long string?

Tags: css

Today, I was reviewing the CSS for Divi Theme, and I realized that all their styles are in one long string (150 pages worth) in style.css. I have never seen this in a WordPress theme. I'm guessing that there is some compelling reason to do so, but I can't imagine what it is.

I also noticed that there is a style.dev.css files with the line breaks, but why no line breaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main file is minified, so it will be smaller and faster to load. But, the author provided you with the development file version. style.css and style.dev.css are basically the same files, but the dev version is readable, and the main one minified.

All WordPress default CSS/JS files are provided with normal and minified version too (but .min is used for minified file and file without the .min is normal version).

Comment: I will have to go back through the various themes I have have worked in and look for the dev CSS files. Do you know in which version of WordPress they started this practice?

Comment: Not every theme does that and it is not mandatory. Infact, very few themes do that as far as I know. WordPress does this since early 2.0 versions 10 years ago.

Comment: I have been using WordPress themes (the ones that come with a default install) since Twenty Ten. I have never seen the minified version in any of them, including Twenty Seventeen.

Comment: Default TwentySomething themes don't have that. Mostly, that is used with plugins or with JavaScript only. I minify all my plugins JS/CSS while providing unminified files for development purposes, just like WordPress does. JavaScript can save up to 70% in size with minification CSS up to 30%.

Comment: 30% of what? File size? Characters? Load time? Run time? Download time?

And why would removing chars have such a difference between JS and CSS?

Comment: File size. And smaller files load faster.

Comment: @NoraMcDougall-Collins This isn't specific to Wordpress - in fact it is quite common in any website development for the reasons that Milan Petrovic says. It is*entirely down to the theme/plugin/website developer whether they do this or not, its nothing to do with the version of Wordpress. In fact it has *always* been possible to do this in WP, because it is nothing more than a valid stylesheet so has no effect when its included instead of the "full" version.